# Is the secure-connect-DBNAME.zip safe to upload to a repository?

Tags: java, github, cassandra, cql, datastax-astra

I have been using DataStax and I'm about to push to my repository, is it safe to have the `secure-connect-DBNANE.zip` on the repo? I would suppose so since it's required to make queries but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Datastax documentation](https://docs.astra.datastax.com/docs/obtaining-database-credentials) does mention:

> Be careful when sharing connection details. Providing this information to another user grants them access to your Astra database and ownership capabilities, such as making modifications to the database.
>
> For security, delete downloaded connection credentials after sending them to your teammate.

That does not strike me as something you should have in a Git repository.

You should rather re-download that file when you need it in a new cloned instance of your repository.

> Alternatively, you can right-click the Download credentials link, copy the link source, and then use a curl command to download the secure-connect-database_name.zip file:
>
> ```
> curl -L "<secure-connect-database_name-download-URL>" > database_name.zip
> ```

Comment: URL for download is available only for 5 minutes, if I remember correctly

Comment: @AlexOtt Is there any API to trigger a new URL?

Comment: I'm not sure - at least there was no 3 months ago... But take into account that without username/password, the secure bundle is useless, so if you don't put them into git repo, people couldn't use just secure bundle to connect to the database

Comment: @AlexOtt OK, so even with its name "secure", this file would not be too "sensitive" and could be stored in a Git repository?

Comment: it's not the best practice, but could be possible if it's used for non-critical data...

Comment: @AlexOtt OK. The best practice should remain, I suppose, to keep that file in an external referential, like a vault, as opposed to a public Git repository.

Comment: Yep, any secrets storage would be nice